# Laravel Dusk - Element [iframe] is not visible

Tags: laravel, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webdriver, laravel-dusk

I need to access a website which uses iframe (TrustArc) like:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/?type=example&amp;site=example.com&amp;action=notice&amp;country=gb&amp;locale=en&amp;behavior=expressed&amp;layout=default_eu&amp;from=https://consent.trustarc.com/" id="pop-frame001407710514252325" title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager" tabindex="1" scrolling="no" style="border: 0px; border-radius: 2px; overflow: hidden; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); display: block; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
```

When I run :

```
$html = $browser->visit('https://www.example.com');
$browser->driver->takeScreenshot(base_path('tests/Browser/screenshots/logged.png'));
<?php echo "<img src='/tests/Browser/screenshots/logged.png'></img>"; ?>
```

I see that iframe is over the window also when I take HTML and show on my frontend iframe is there.

But when I check page iframe with:

```
$browser->assertVisible("iframe");
```

I got :

> Element [iframe] is not visible. Failed asserting that false is true.

also when I try:

```
$browser->driver->switchTo()->frame(0);
// $browser->driver->switchTo()->frame('iframe[src*="https://consent-pref.trustarc.com/?type=opentable&amp;site=opentable.com&amp;action=notice&amp;country=gb&amp;locale=en&amp;behavior=expressed&amp;layout=default_eu&amp;from=https://consent.trustarc.com/"]');
```

I got message

> no such frame

I tried to between each step to add sleep(10); but I got the same error messages.

How I can solve the problem? Why I can't switch to iframe?
Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

I also tried:

```
$browser->assertSourceHas('title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"');
```

and it's passed, so iframe is there but I don't know how to access to that frame

UPDATE 2.

I also tried this but no success:

```
$browser->ensurejQueryIsAvailable();
$browser->assertSourceHas('title="TrustArc Cookie Consent Manager"');
       $browser->script("$('iframe').attr('name','something')");

$browser->driver->switchTo()->frame('something');
$browser->waitUntil('.call')->click('.call');
sleep(10);
$browser->driver->switchTo()->defaultContent();
```

Comment: Any ideas?.....

Comment: The `frame()` method accepts an id, a name or an element. Try `$browser->driver->switchTo()->frame($browser->element('iframe[src*="..."]'));`

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir I solve like this $iframe_id = $browser->attribute('body > div.truste_box_overlay > div > iframe', 'id');

$browser->driver->switchTo()->frame($iframe_id);